# Make text stay inside a parent div, above an image?

Tags: css, position

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img width="100%" src="images/some.jpg"> 
    <div class="header">
        <h1>my header</h1>    
        Some more<br>text
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.header {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 52px;
    left: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Now, when I resize the page, there is 1 problem:

1. At some point, the text is not above the image to 100% any longer, but why?

Comment: What's the image size?

Comment: Does it matter? I want it to always be 100% so that it scales upon resizing.

Comment: You mean that you want the text always above the image or you want the text always ontop of the image?

Comment: Above the image, it should look like if the text belongs to the image.

Comment: Well I'm confused because the text is always inside the div and at the top. Not sure where you want it. When you resize the page it slips out the left side. Is that what you want to stop?

Comment: It slips out to the right ... but yes, this is what I want to stop.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the right. Its early in the morning, you know how it is!

Comment: you set top to 0, so it place at the top always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo you want it like this?

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>my header</h1>    
        Some more<br>text
        <img width="100%" src="/image/some-image.jpg"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 52px;
    left: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cT7Sy/

Comment: What's changed? Care to explain?

Comment: If you compare my code with yours i've changed your image position into the `header` and added a width: 100%.

Comment: When you add an answer can you try explain your code. Not make people compare your code with the OP. Explain your answer so everyone can understand not just the OP.

Comment: Sure, will do in the future :)